# Cannot access protected property

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm learning Laravel's(4) Eloquent and I'm lost when it comes to accessing properties from the returned Eloquent object. This code doesn't work:

```
public function show($email)
{
    $client = Client::where('email', $email)->get();
    echo var_dump($client->items);

}
```

The `items` property, which contains all the sub properties including `email`, is protected which means I can't access it by, say: `$client->items->email`. So my question how do I access the properties of `$client` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get() is for getting all of the records based on the query, meaning it'll return something you can loop through, for example if you change `var_dump($client->items)` to `var_dump($client[0]->items` it would work. Instead if you need just ONE record, call the Eloquent model with first() instead of get().